# Pandas series index datetime sort

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to sort a Pandas Series which has `dtype=<M8[ns`

Yet, the sorting goes well for the first few entries, and then becomes quite random.

I'm using this code

```
d_series = pd.Series(dates_count)
d_series.index = pd.to_datetime(d_series.index)
d_series.sort_index(inplace=True)
d_series
```

The specific issue is here:

```
2018-11-04      3
2018-11-06    338
2018-11-07    319
```

Since we didn't have those months yet. To confirm that the date-notation is not different from what I expect, this is how the series starts:

```
2018-03-15      2
2018-03-21      1
2018-03-22      1
```

As you can tell, the formatting is 'yyyy/mm/dd' but somehow going wrong.

Comment: Your example output looks perfectly sorted to me?

Comment: what do you expect other than what you already have?

Comment: we have no entries in 2018-11-04 :)

Comment: Thanks guys, solved it though by defining a format. I had assumed it'd error out if it couldn't parse it. My bad :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not specify how to sort the dates, so I think the best guess was wrong. By defining the format, it was fixed.